# DataTimeIndex to ISO 8601 string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe `t` whose index (in the form of a datetime64 object) I want to convert to an ISO 8601 string.

```
t.index

DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 02:00:00', '2011-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)
```

When I convert the index to a series and then use [.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to access the datetimelike properties of the series, I am left with a `datetime` object that contains both formats:

```
times = times.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:%SZ')
print(str(times))

datetime
2011-01-01 00:00:00    2011-01-01T00:00:00Z
2011-01-01 01:00:00    2011-01-01T01:00:00Z
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2011-01-01T02:00:00Z
2011-01-01 03:00:00    2011-01-01T03:00:00Z
2011-01-01 04:00:00    2011-01-01T04:00:00Z
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Why does this return two different formats side by side? How does one only return a string in the second (ISO 8601) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `to_series`, it will copy the index into values and create the series which also carry over the origina index.

```
times = times.to_series()
print(str(times))

datetime
2011-01-01 00:00:00    2011-01-01 00:00:00
2011-01-01 01:00:00    2011-01-01 01:00:00
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2011-01-01 02:00:00
2011-01-01 03:00:00    2011-01-01 03:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, but `to_series()` is necessary to apply the dt accessor.   How does one prevent carrying over the original index or drop the original index if I am only interested in the output from the second, converted series?

Comment: times.to_series().reset_index(drop=True) @the_darkside